# Remove last two words from a string

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I am totally new to `preg_replace`, but the code below removes the last word from my string:

```
preg_replace('/\W\w+\s*(\W*)$/', '$1', $var);
```

I am trying to modify it, so that it removes the last **two** words.

The only thing that I could think of was to replace `$1` with `$2`, but this seems to not have any effect at all and was probably just dumb :/

The string in question looks kinda like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Source: LOREM
```

I would like to remove `Source: LOREM`

Comment: How do you define a word? and what characters can separate words?

Comment: `$1` refers not to quantity, but to ordinality. It's your first matched sequence.

Comment: What would your expected output be for this string: "Do I like Cheese? No."

Comment: Or you could just run the routine that removes the last word, twice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple regular expression could match a space, followed by any number of letters (or a colon), followed by a space, followed by any number of letters at the end of a string:

```
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Source: LOREM";
$str = preg_replace( "/\s[a-z:]+\s[a-z]+$/i", "", $str );

// Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
echo $str;
```

The expression broken down follows:

```
\s       // Single space
[a-z:]+  // Any letter, a to z, or a colon, 1 or more times
\s       // Single space
[a-z]+   // Any letter, a to z, 1 or more times
$        // End of string
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/G22LnDDY

One other method would be to use `explode` to create an array of words, and remove the last two.

```
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Source: LOREM";
$words = explode( " ", $str );
array_splice( $words, -2 );

// Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
echo implode( " ", $words );
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/6XwqvwuP

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, but none seems to work (`Source: Lorem` is not removed). Its strange, since that code to remove only 1 word works fine. Its probably a problem related to my code. I will keep trying it and if I dont get it fixed, I will update my question with the code snippet. I hope its fine if i dont accept any answer as of now.

Comment: @Andrej Both methods above work. Check your code again. I've provided links to two functional demos that you can play with.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, Jonathan. Codepad.org looks like a great way to test my whole snippet! I am sure I will get it to work sooner or later! p.s. could the problem be that I have multiple strings and I do use the expression in a for each loop?

Comment: @Andrej Provide me a codepad link to your setup and I'll let you know.

Comment: I put it online at http://codepad.org/9ShnX8xP . However the whole code doesnt work there, since a file (simplehtmldomparser) is missing. If you need me to include that one too, just let me know! And thanks again for taking your time to look at it!

Comment: @Andrej What is the `echo implode( " ", $words );` line outputting?

Comment: Can you do `var_dump( $descr->plaintext );` and share the output?

Comment: I am probably being very stupid now, but in the example you made, I still see `Source: CBS` in the "Output" box?

Comment: I think you're looking in the wrong place: http://i.imgur.com/hsbBu.png Now how the output doesn't have multiple new lines like the input did.

Comment: Oh I get it! So I would take that output now and use it for one of the various methods that have been posted here? *Trying* -> WORKS! :) Thanks alot for your efforts! I would double upvote your answer if I could!

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to use regexp here. Assuming you define a word as anything surrounded by a space:

```
$words = explode(' ', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Source: LOREM');
if (count($words) >= 2) {
    array_pop($words);
    array_pop($words);
}
$words = implode(' ', $words);
```

Or:

```
$words = explode(' ', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Source: LOREM');
if (count($words) >= 2) {
    $words = array_slice($words, 0, count($words) - 2);
}
$words = implode(' ', $words);
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, but none seems to work (`Source: Lorem` is not removed). Its strange, since that code to remove only 1 word works fine. Its probably a problem related to my code. I will keep trying it and if I dont get it fixed, I will update my question with the code snippet. I hope its fine if i dont accept any answer as of now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = ' would like to remove Source: LOREM';
$str =  preg_replace('/(.*)\s+([a-zA-Z]+):\s+([a-zA-Z]+)$/', '$1', $str);
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

The $1, is really a grouped capture for replacement so think of it as $n, $n+1. You only have 1 group in your regex the parens (). So you'll need a second set. If you don't actually need to swap something out, you can use a more targeted approach.

.*(?=\s\D+\s)

Should get you a lot closer.
Also, a life saver for me (ok time saver really) is http://regexpal.com/
I don't code RegEx without it.