# PHP: How can I remove from String the last word?

Tags: php, string, replace

How can I remove, with PHP, the last word from a String?

For example the string `"Hi, I'm Gian Marco"` would become `"Hi, I'm Gian"`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove last two words from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541808/remove-last-two-words-from-a-string)

Comment: I don't know the contenf of String! I just want to remove the last word (not last char).

Comment: @MamounBenghezal How is this a duplicate of a java question?

Comment: @Loko, oops my mistake.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

try with this :

```
$txt = "Hi, I'm Gian Marco";
$str= preg_replace('/\W\w+\s*(\W*)$/', '$1', $txt);
echo $str
```

out put

```
Hi, I'm Gian
```

Comment: GOOD(Ty)!!! And if the string end with numbers like "Gian@Marco.it 29348 39388" and I want to remove "39388"? (i don't know the numbers)

Comment: @Kiuki Try with this : $str= preg_replace('~\\s+\\S+$~', "", $txt);

Answer (score 18):

check this

```
 <?php
$str ='"Hi, I\'m Gian Marco" will be "Hi, I\'m Gian"';
$words = explode( " ", $str );
array_splice( $words, -1 );

echo implode( " ", $words );
?>
```

source : [Remove last two words from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541808/remove-last-two-words-from-a-string)

Comment: Upvoting this as it answers the OP's question without using regex.

Answer (score 13):

You can do it with regular expression. (see answer of *Ahmed Ziani.*)

However, in PHP you can also do it using some inbuilt function. see the code below

```
$text = "Hi, I'm Gian Marco";
$last_space_position = strrpos($text, ' ');
$text = substr($text, 0, $last_space_position);
echo $text;
```

Comment: its `strpos($text, ' ');` not `strrpos($text, ' ');`

Answer (score 7):

The current solution is ok if you do not know the last word and the string length is short.

In case you do know it, for instance when looping a concat string for a query like this:

```
        foreach ($this->id as $key => $id) {
            $sql.=' id =' . $id . ' OR ';
        }
```

A better solution:

```
        $sql_chain = chop($sql_chain," OR ");
```

Be aware that preg_replace with a regex is **VERY** slow with long strings.
Chop is 100 times faster in such case and perf gain can be substantial.

Answer (score 4):

The regular exprerssion can cause issues when the string has special characters. Why not simply go with this:

```
$input = "Hi, I'm Gian Marco";
$output = substr($input, 0, strrpos($input, " "));
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 3):

This code may help you :

```
$str="Hi, I'm Gian Marco";

$split=explode("",$str);
$split_rem=array_pop($split);
foreach ($split as $k=>$v)
{
   echo $v.'';
}
```

Comment: Your `explode`  need a `delimiter` as *a space* not *an empty string* or you will get a Fatal error:*Uncaught ValueError: explode(): Argument #1 ($separator) cannot be empty*. Same notice with concatenation in `foreach` need *a space*. or without foreach just using `implode(" ", $split)`.

Answer (score 0):

Explode the `str` with `explode(delimiter, string)` into an array `$words`, take the first word put it into `$res`, and iterate over words *the count of `$words` times* **minus one** which is exclude the last word.

```php
$str = "Hi, I'm Gian Marco";
$words = explode(" ",$str);
$res = $words[0];
for ($i=1; $i < count($words) - 1; $i++) { 
    $res .= ' '.$words[$i]; // concatenation with a space.
}
echo $res; // Hi, I'm Gian
```

Answer (score 0):

In search for ltrim and rtrim alternatives (to trim a whole first/last word) I came across posts like these. Just want to share the functions I wrote when any other is landing here like I did.

Find the first occurrence of a given word and if it is the first word, return the sentence without that first word.

```
function leftStrTrim($sentence, $word){    
  $wordLength = strlen($word);
  $wordStart = strpos($sentence, $word);    
  if($wordStart!==false && $wordStart==0){
    return substr($sentence, $wordLength);
  }
  return $sentence;    
}
```

Find the last occurrence of a given word and if it is the last word, return the sentence without that last word.

```
function righStrTrim($sentence, $word){    
  $wordLength = strlen($word);
  $wordStart = strrpos($sentence, $word);    
  if($wordStart!==false && $wordStart == strlen($sentence)-$wordLength){
    return substr($sentence, 0, $wordLength*-1);
  }
  return $sentence;    
}
```