# How to delete all chars from end to first space of PHP variable?

Tags: php, string, variables, char

I would like to delete one last word of String variable in PHP. I tried to do it according to this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29428662/10490051. But it doesn't solve my problem.

I would like to use it for SQL argument:

```
$sql_request = "SELECT fullname FROM names WHERE lastname='johnson' and city='oxford' ";


$sql_request = preg_replace('/\W\w+\s*(\W*)$/', '$1', $sql_request);

echo $sql_request;
```

Specifically I need to delete whole last argument: **city='oxford'**.
(I need to delete all from end to first space)
But result of my code will be:

```
SELECT fullname FROM names WHERE lastname='johnson' and city='
```

but I need this:

```
SELECT fullname FROM names WHERE lastname='johnson' and
```

So how to delete whole last argument and not only part of them?
Thank you.

Comment: Check this code: `\w+=\W\w+\s*(\W*)$`

Comment: I see: _Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:_

Comment: Seems like the wrong approach. Do you not control the generation of the query?

Comment: Can be it with "preg_replace" ?

Comment: @El_Vanja what do you mean?

Comment: @Dominik `preg_replace('/\w+=\W\w+\s*(\W*)$/', '', $sql_request)`

Comment: I mean when this query was first generated with the condition `city='oxford'`, was it something you generated or does this come from some part of code you did not write and thus do not control? Because the proper approach would be not generating that condition in the first place, not removing it afterwards.

Comment: Ok, it´s right.  What count of means 'number' ?

Comment: For the record, calling `trim()` on the input string will set up the dupe target to work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to dance with the REGEX Devil, you can use the simpler mechanism

```
$sql_request = "SELECT fullname FROM names WHERE lastname='johnson' and city='oxford' ";

$sql_request = trim($sql_request);
$pos = strrpos($sql_request, ' ');
$sql_request = substr($sql_request, 0, $pos);   
echo $sql_request;
```

RESULT

```
SELECT fullname FROM names WHERE lastname='johnson' and
```

Or wrapping it all into a single line

```
$sql_request = substr( $sql_request, 0, strrpos(trim($sql_request), ' '));     
echo $sql_request;
```

#### Update based on question in the comment

```
$pos = strrpos($sql_request, ' and');
$sql_request = substr( $sql_request, 0, $pos);   
echo $sql_request;
```

Or wrapping it all into a single line

```
$sql_request = substr( $sql_request, 0, strrpos($sql_request, ' and'));     
echo $sql_request;
```

Comment: And How to do it if I would like to delete AND too? Thank´s

Comment: See update, just change the search to look for `and`

Comment: Actually thinking about it, now you dont need the trim even